# Confusion about a step when proving the Monotone convergence theorem in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The proof for the theorem is natural to me except for one step, so I will only keep the parts that confused me.

Theorem 2.4.1 (The Monotone Convergence Theorem). Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ be $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on X. Suppose that
$$
f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \ldots
$$
and
$$
f(x)=\lim _n f_n(x)
$$
hold at every $x$ in $X$. Then $\int f d \mu=\lim _n \int f_n d \mu$.

Proof. For each $n$ choose a nondecreasing sequence $\left\{g_{n, k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of simple $[0,+\infty)$-valued measurable functions such that $f_n=\lim _k g_{n, k}$ .

For each $n$ define a function $h_n$ by

$$
h_n=\max \left(g_{1, n}, g_{2, n}, \ldots, g_{n, n}\right) .
$$

Then $\left\{h_n\right\}$ is a nondecreasing sequence of simple $[0,+\infty)$-valued measurable functions that satisfy $h_n \leq f_n$ and $f=\lim _n h_n$. **I got confused when proving $h_n$ converges to $f$.** Let $h = \lim _n h_n$

The thoughts are $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall m \in [1,k]$, $g_{m,k} \leq h_{k} \leq f_{k}$, then by first letting $k$ to the infinity, and then letting $m$ goes to infinity, we have the results.

Proving $h \leq f$ is acceptable to me, which based on if we have two convergent sequences $\left\{a_n\right\}$ to $a$, $\left\{b_n\right\}$ to $b$, if $\forall n, a_n \leq b_n$, then $a \leq b$. Plus do some modification for the $\infty$ cases since we also have monotonicity.

**But the reverse side is arcane, why we can first letting $k$ to the infinity, getting $f_m \leq h$ and then letting $m$ goes to infinity, getting $f \leq h$?**

I think one way to deal with is through $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall m \in [1,k]$, $g_{m,k} \leq h_{k} $ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \forall k \in [m,\infty)$, $g_{m,k} \leq h_{k} $

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't we do that? They are just using the definitions in getting $f_m\le h$ first  and then $f \le h$.

Comment: The limit of $g_{mk}$  is defined as $\forall m, \forall \epsilon >0$, there exists some $K$, $\forall k >K$, such that ....., so the $K$ is somewhat reliable on $m$, but in the inequality $g_{m,k} \leq h_k$, the $m$ is reliable on $k$, which gets me confused.

Comment: So How can we choose some large enough $k$, such that $f_m \leq h$, then how can we choose a large enough $m$ (it is always bounded by $k$).

Comment: If we have $\forall m, \forall k$, $g_{m,k} \leq h_k$, then we can have $\forall m$, $f_m \leq h$

Comment: You don't need $\forall m, \forall k$. It is enough to have $\forall m$ and $\forall k \ge m$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got the answer as shown in the last paragraph I Added in the question.